# Regular expression for turning number into number with decimal precision of 3

Tags: sql, regex, replace, oracle11g, toad

I have a column with numeric values in which the last 3 digits should actually be behind the decimal point.

e.g.

- 89302500
- 1260840
- 218580

I need a regular expression that will put the decimal point before the last 3 digits:

- 89302.500
- 1260.840
- 218.580

I'm using the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to change the format of values, but I can't find a way to do this. Is it possible to write such regular expression and use it to replace value format?

Comment: What should happen if there are less than three numbers? Exactly three numbers?

Comment: If they are always numeric, how about `colval / 1000`?

Comment: @pzp There isn't any cell with exactly three digits or less.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Could you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex to achieve this, then you can use a regex like this:

```
(\d*)(\d{3})
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV1bR1/1)**

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm), you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number,
                 '([[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]{3})',
                 '\1.\2') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use regular expressions on numbers.  If you want a *number* with a precision of 3:

```
select cast(col / 1000 as number(18, 3))
```

If you want this expressed as a string, then use `to_char()` on `col / 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by [Tony Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18747/tony-andrews)

```
colval / 1000
```